# Как преобразовать код так, чтобы было хотя бы два метода?

Tags: java

Первый метод public static void main(String[] agrs) - точка входа, а второй - реализация задания. У меня реализация в public static void main(String[] agrs), но надо сделать по другому. 
Вот мой код:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Lab14 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\file.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\mahesh.txt")));
            String s="";
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                out.write(s.toUpperCase()+"\n");
            }
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот пример, но другого кода:

```
public class Task1 {
    public Task1() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printRes("CAFE");
        printRes("my");
        printRes("MY");
        printRes("CATE");
        printRes("ABCD");
        printRes("0");
        printRes("9");
        printRes("10");
        printRes("333");
    }

    public static int hexStringToInt(String s) {
        int res = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s), 16);
        return res;
    }

    static void printRes(String s) {
        System.out.print("s:" + s + " result: ");

        try {
            System.out.println(hexStringToInt(s));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException var2) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION!" + var2.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Что бы сделать по другому надо написать что именно и как именно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Lab14 {
    static void copyFileAsUpper(String fileNameFrom, String fileNameTo) {
        try
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileNameFrom);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileNameTo)));
            String s;
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                out.write(s.toUpperCase()+"\n");
            }
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        copyFileAsUpper(
            "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\file.txt",
            "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\mahesh.txt"
        );
    }
}
```